# Is there any way to delay a Python Script till an Application is running?

Tags: python, file, time, file-handling, notepad

I want the Python Code to open Notepad and let the user type in it, by the time it should not execute the rest of the code. After I close notepad, it should resume the script from where it left. Is there any way to do this? Or should I try a different approach?

#### What have I Tried:

- Here is the code so far -

```
with open('file.txt','w') as file: #this is to create an empty file
    file.close()
    pass
os.startfile('file.txt')
time.sleep() # what value should I enter for time.sleep? or is there a module to do this?
```

- I possibly can run a while loop to check whether the `notepad.exe` is running or not, if it is, if it's not, it should break out of the loop and execute the rest of the code.
  However, the problem is how do I check if `notepad.exe` is running?
- Running a while loop to delete the file, if it get's an error, means the program is still running, but the problem is if it does  not get the error, It will delete the file.

> It would be better, if when launching of the program, it takes the process ID of it, and only wait for it to terminated. So that other instances  of notepad won't be affected.

Comment: Is this perhaps an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? *Why* do you need Notepad opened? Why not just have the user input the text directly in Python, and then write to the txt? Or - just have Python trigger the Notepad shell, allow the user to do whatever, but then just have Python wait for user input of say "Y" for "Done using notepad". that way it doesn't have to actually "communicate" with the apps which could get complicated

Comment: I want it to take the input in a text file because I want to read the file line by line, and want to take the input all at once, I sure can take the input in a loop and then keep appending it to an empty list, but I want to make it more user-friendly kind of. So that, when the user is done typing, he can just close notepad and the rest will run.

Comment: So the user opens notepad, types something, saves/closes, and then you want Python to take what the txt file has as a single string?

Comment: No prob. I'll stick with the loop approach but still if there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> startfile()  returns as soon as the associated application is
> launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and
> no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

If you know the path of the application to open the file with, you could use subprocess.Popen() which allows for you to wait.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([
    'C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe', 
    'path\\to\\file'
])

(output, err) = p.communicate()  

#This makes the wait possible
p_status = p.wait()
```

See:
http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: Thanks! I was exactly looking something like this! It works